# Retrieve Outlook Meeting Room Locations using JAVA

Tags: java, email, outlook

I am trying to send an Outlook meeting invite using JAVA. I have managed to send the invite using JAVA mail API as discussed in this post

[How to send an iCal meeting request using Java Mail, and receive the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121715/how-to-send-an-ical-meeting-request-using-java-mail-and-recieve-the-response)

The problem is that here Location of the Meeting Room is hard-coded.

```
"LOCATION:Conference room\n"
```

I need to retrieve the available rooms from the Outlook and then select one of these rooms as my meeting room location.

Answer (score 0):

You may find EWS (Exchange Web Services) helpful. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

Also you may try to automate Outlook. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096).