# Send Outlook Meeting Invite using Java

Tags: java

I want to send a Outlook Meeting Invite using Java.Can somebody please share the code for the same?

Thanks & Regards,
Richa

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question which was voted closed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975031/how-to-send-a-meeting-invite-closed

Answer (score 5):

An outlook invitation consists of an iCalendar request with some specific requirements. To generate an iCalendar request in Java, you can use [iCal4j](https://www.ical4j.org/). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook) is a description of what Outlook needs.