# Sending Outlook meeting requests without accept/decline option

Tags: .net, outlook

I am sending an Outlook meeting request with my .NET-program using the following as a source:
[Sending Outlook meeting requests without Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook)
This worked well for me, but I still have one problem/question.

If I send an invitation directly with Outlook I have the possibility to define that I DONT want an answer (accept, decline, ..) from the invited people. So if the invited people open my mail they dont see accept, decline... buttons.

I want this behavior also if I send auto-generated mails with my .NET-program. Is there an option to deactive the answer-feature programmatically? So that receivers DONT see accept, decline... buttons if they open my auto-generated mails?

I already tried to set RSVP = False, DISALLOW-COUNTER = True:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=receiver@mail.de;RSVP=FALSE:receiver@mail.de
SET X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
.
.
.
END:VEVENT
```

I saved two ICS-Files with Outlook - one with answer enabled and one with answer disabled. The above two lines were the only different ones, but it doesn't work in my generated message. If I open the mail it still shows the accept, decline, ... buttons. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried RSVP=FALSE (Just in case its case-sensitive)?

Comment: Yes i tried it, still dont works.

Comment: This works fine for me, you need to share the full ICS file. I don't get the Accept/Tentative/Decline when RSVP=FALSE.

Comment: I confirmed RSVP=FALSE is case-sensitive in the spec. However, setting it to FALSE for me still has outlook 2007 prompting accept/decline too. Not sure what the magic settings OL is wanting to suppress accept/decline. METHOD=PUBLISH in event too :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about Outlook's "Request Responses" option.  When that is unchecked, Outlook generates .ics files with RSVP=FALSE for all attendees.  When the attendee receives this, they will still see Accept, Tentative, Decline buttons, but these buttons won't send a response, they will simply determine how or if this invitation is added to their own calendar.

If "Request Responses" is checked then RSVP=TRUE is used for all attendees which will cause their Accept/Tentative/Decline buttons to also show options for Send the Response Now, Do Not Send a Response (this is equivalent to what happens when Request Responses wasn't checked), and Edit the Response before Sending.