# How to send Outlook tasks requests by mail without Outlook?

Tags: c#, asp-classic, outlook, icalendar, tnef

I need to replicate the `Outlook` feature/functionnality to send some tasks requests to someone ([see here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/assign-a-task-to-someone-else-HP005242813.aspx)) but with mails sent from a webserver using `ASP.NET C#` and without Outlook installed on the webserver (thus using outlook automation is not possible).

I already check what are the possiblities to do this, and it seems a common way to send tasks to someone is to generate an `.ics` file in `iCalendar` format, and include that file to the mail ([see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook)).

It works great, however there is no equivalence of tasks sent by outlook :

- Events (VEVENT) have a start date and end date (like a task) but no "completion" field (which make sense since it is an event, not a task).
- Todos (VTODO) have only a due date, no start date or end date [and it is not supported by outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook#Calendar_compatibility).

I checked myself what Outlook exactly send in a mail containing a task request : It include a `winmail.dat` file (with `content-type:application/ms-tnef`) encoded as `Base64`. Inside that file (which is a binary file) there is a reference to `IPM.TaskRequest` which seems to be what i need.

I checked the web and found some TNEF parsers, but i need the oposite : **to generate from C# code a TNEF file that would contains a task request**. I would like to know if there is a way to do that. Using a library (free or not) is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even if outlook were installed on the web server, outlook automation on a server is generally a bad idea.

However, have you looked at Exchange Web Services? It provides a complete object model to integrate with outlook. Obviously it's tied to outlook (unlike ics), but it does seem to fit your use case.

EWS overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

Working with tasks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhruvkh/archive/2012/04/06/working-with-tasks-using-exchange-web-services.aspx

Comment: Two questions : 1) does it need to have Microsoft Exchange installed ? or is it available as a standalone library that i can add to any C# project ? 2) i see many references to Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2007 in the page you submitted, does this solution work for sending tasks requests to someone who use Outlook 2003 ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I believe EWS is part of your exchange server installation. I'm not sure about backward compatibility with outlook 2003 either, sorry.