# Is it possible to create a TNEF file from java?

Tags: java, email, outlook, tnef

I would like to send a task to outlook from a java backend.

I found this thread here which is not resolved (and from 2012):
[How to send Outlook tasks requests by mail without Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455104/how-to-send-outlook-tasks-requests-by-mail-without-outlook)

Does it exist a library that can make a [TNEF-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format) for java?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [Apache POI Project](http://poi.apache.org/hmef/). Seems like HMEF is a pure Java implementation of Microsoft's TNEF

Comment: It seems like it is only for reading TNEF-files. Second line on the page you linked says "HMEF provides a read-only api", or am I missing something?