# .ics file isn't displayed as Calendar event in Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, gmail, icalendar

I've created a .ics file using iCal .Net. Now i'm trying to send it.

When i'm sending it from my Outlook account to another outlook account, it's displayed as an email with attachment (not as a calendar event).

[image: From outlook to outlook]

However when i'm sending this file from my outlook account to an gmail email address and open it in gmail i see the calendar event.

[image: Gmail calendar event]

Also when i'm sending this file from gmail to outlook the file is displayed as calendar event too.

[image: Calendar event from gmail to outlook]

What could be the reason? Why .ics file which is sent from outlook to outlook is not shown as calendar event?

Comment: Did you try to export a meeting request in Outlook, save it using ics file format and then compare yours and exported one? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: I've tried to create a calendar event, save it as a .ics file and send it from outlook to my outlook address. And the result is the same - i'm receiving an email with attachment (not a calendar event).  I also compared my ics file and the ics file which were created from the calendar event import - they are almost the same (no significant changes). So i think the reason is somewhere in how i am sending (not in  what i am sending).

Comment: You can try to save and check the received files (ics).

Comment: The point is that Outlook behaves so even if i do "Forward as iCalendar" to myself on a Calendar event which i've created in Outlook manually. I still see an email with attachment instead of a Calendar event. P.S. if i do "Forward" (not "Forward as iCalendar") the Calendar event displayed OK (as it should).... What's the difference between "Forward" and "Forward as iCalendar"?

Comment: Have you found any solution ? Because I have exact the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462096/4940366) you have to insert ICS file content as an email part. Attaching the .ICS file is optional.
Also it would be nice to see resulted .EML file

Comment: @kban Did you found the solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

while creating event set attachment type =  "text/calendar; method=REQUEST"

While cancelling event set attachment type =  "text/calendar; method=CANCEL"